# Find out, by lambda, whether a list contains an another list value

Tags: c#, list, lambda

How can I do this by lambda? To find out whether the two lists have the same value(s).

```
    void Main()
    {
        var list1 = new List<string>{
            "a", "b", "c"
        };

        var list2 = new List<string>{
            "c", "d", "e"
        };

        bool listsHaveSameValue = false;
        foreach(var list1Value in list1){
              listsHaveSameValue = list2.Any(c => c.Equals(list1Value));
              if(listsHaveSameValue){
                   break;
              }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(listsHaveSameValue.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether the lists have all the same values (i.e., identical lists but allowing for different orders)?  Whether list2 has all the values that list1 does?  Or whether they have at least 1 item in common?

Comment: What is your motivation for requiring a lambda?

Comment: Your current code only checks for last Value.

Comment: In these 7 answers, none of one even didn't help you?

Comment: Motivation to use lambda expression is to make the code more shorter without need to loop the another list.

Comment: JLRishe: trying to determine whether they have at least 1 item in common.

Comment: Tilak: true, thanks for noticing that. Edited the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into `Intersect`.

```
var list1 = new List<string>{ "a", "b", "c"};
var list2 = new List<string>{ "c", "d", "e"};

var doubles = list1.Intersect(list2);
bool listsHaveSameValue = doubles.Any();
```

Actually there is no real need to use a lambda (as you've asked).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [*`Enumerable.Intersect`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<string>{
            "a", "b", "c"
        };

            var list2 = new List<string>{
            "c", "d", "e"
        };

           IEnumerable<string> dubvalues = list2.Intersect(list1);

            foreach (var i in dubvalues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i); // Output is c
            }
        }
```

Here is a *[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/ZsTWW3)*.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively searching for last value.

To determine whether all elements are same (irrespective of order in list)

You should use

```
 listsHaveSameValue = listsHaveSameValue && list2.Any(c => c.Equals(list1Value));
```

instead of

```
 listsHaveSameValue = list2.Any(c => c.Equals(list1Value));
```

One of the Linq way to determine whether `list1` and `list2` have same elements is to use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

```
listsHaveSameValue = list1.OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x=>x)
```

Comment: No, this isn't what the question was asking for.

Comment: @JLRishe I understand, but part of the question is "How can I do this by lambda?" and the logic of "this" is wrong

Comment: Your first line still makes no sense.  In the example above, the item in common happens to be the last item in list1, but nowhere did the question indicate that the asker just wants to check whether the last item matches.

Comment: I agree with you and deleted first line

Answer (score 0):

your should use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb460136.aspx)

```
var list3 = list2.Intersect(list1);
```

list3 contains the elements which occur in **both** lists

Answer (score 0):

This will check for the existence of at least one common element.

```
list1.Any(i => list2.Contains(i));
```

Comment: Be aware, that If you have collections of your own model classes, this would not work, only for primitive types.
The compiler does not know how to compare your model classes. In that case, you could override your model classes Equals method, and from now on the Contains method uses that overridden Equals method for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Intersect(list2).Any()
```

should return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.IsTrue(list1.Any(x => list2.Any(y => x.YourProperty == y.YourProperty)));
```

It is basically the same as two loops, with a comparing if statement.
I think this would achieve what you asked for, but in this case, I would probably use the double loop.